# CSS horizontal inline multiple photo placement in single row: Firefox Issue

Tags: html, css, gallery, photo

I've read several questions regarding this topic and I've tried different methods and I'm unable to resolve the following issue.

I have created a gallery of photos that are placed in a single horizontal row. There is a parent DIV container that is 100% of the browser with. It has a child DIV container with a large width (4000px+) to hold the images inside in a single row. With some PHP code, photos are placed inside automatically from a folder.

The entire system works perfect in Chrome, Safari, and Opera. Even though I have 4 photos and the child DIV has a high width, the browser stops the horizontal scrolling of the gallery frame after the fourth photo.

In Firefox, however, the browser displays the entire blank space following the last photo. This means that one is able to scroll for a long time after the last photo is displayed. I have tried different ways of resolving this but I'm unable to do so.

The CSS:

```css
#photoparent {
 border-top: 1px solid white;
 clear: both;
 height: 600px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

#photochild {
 background-color: #000000;
 margin-right: -5800px; 
}


#photochild img {
 float: left;
 padding-right: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to achieve this in a simpler way. Since images are inline elements, you could set up your code like this and get the horizontal scrolling effect that will be perfectly sized to the number of images.

CSS

```
.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="">
  <img src="">
  <img src="">
   ....
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. The only change is that I used "overflow-y: hidden;" and "overflow-x: auto;" to display the horizontal scroll bar but not the vertical one to achieve the final look.